# Postgres running but not functioning with no errors

Tags: postgresql

A bit odd, but I followed the instructions here for installing and getting up and running on Postgres. I'm in the command prompt, commands seem to go through, but then nothing seems to take (except \l or \q). I've tried command with a semicolon and without. Nothing seems to work. Here is an example (please note that the database is never created):

```
#psql
postgres=# createdb test
postgres-# \l
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(3 rows)

postgres-# createdb test;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "createdb"
LINE 1: createdb test
```

Comment: regarding the first part: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472026

Answer (score 3):

[`createdb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-createdb.html) is a command line tool like `psql`, it's **not** a SQL command.

To create a database within `psql` use the SQL command [`create database`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html)